# Fourier-Laplace Transform of Heaviside Step function multiplied to Sine

Tags: fourier-analysis, physics, laplace-transform, mathematical-physics, integral-transforms

In a Advanced Solid State lecture I encountered the following assertion-
Fourier Transform of $\Theta(t)\sin(\omega_0 t)$ is $\frac{1}{\omega+\omega_0}-\frac{1}{\omega-\omega_0}+i\pi\delta(\omega+\omega_0)$. I do not see how that is. I know that some kind of regularization by doing the Fourier Transformation in complex integral is involved. But I do not know to go past something of the form
$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}\int dt \exp(i(\omega+\omega_0)t)\exp(-(\omega+\omega_0)\alpha)$
 Interestingly, [the wolframalpha output seems to outdo me in this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FourierTransform%5bHeavisideTheta%5bt%5d+Sin%5b+a+t%5d%2C+t%2C+%CF%89%5d)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [table of correspondences for distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions). I use angular frequency $\omega$ and the non-unitary version of the Fourier transform:

$$\sin\omega_0t\Longleftrightarrow -i\pi[\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)]\\
\Theta(t)\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{i\omega}+\pi\delta(\omega)$$

With these correspondences you get

$$\Theta(t)\sin\omega_0t\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{2\pi}\mathcal{F}(\Theta(t))*
\mathcal{F}(\sin\omega_0t)$$

where $*$ stands for convolution. The result of the convolution is

$$\Theta(t)\sin\omega_0t\Longleftrightarrow -\frac12\left[\frac{1}{\omega-\omega_0}-\frac{1}{\omega+\omega_0}\right]-\frac{i\pi}{2}\left[\delta(\omega-\omega_0)-\delta(\omega+\omega_0)\right]$$

Note that WolframAlpha uses the unitary version of the Fourier transform which gives you different constants.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had not thought of this! But I was hoping it would be possible to understand how this is solved in terms of complex integration. For example, this integral is defined only for $Im(\omega)>0$t. Your solution doesn't tell me how! If you feel that is an unfair position to take, I am sorry!

Comment: @DebanjanBasu: I understand. I was just trying to show you an easy and practical way to arrive at a solution. If you want to use this example as an exercise in complex integration, that's OK. In any case, you need to use distributions, and the integrals don't behave the way you normally would expect them to behave, e.g. $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega t}d\omega=\delta(t)$.

Comment: @DebanjanBasu: Do you understand the Fourier transform of the step function? If not it might help to read this: https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf This might also help you understand how to deal (or rather not to deal) with the integrals.