# An integral related to the Fourier transform of $\sin(bx)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

Let $a,b >0$ and consider the following integral:
$$
I(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{ - i a x } \sin( b x )\ dx 
$$

Is there a way to evaluate this integral? This looks very similar to the Fourier transform of the function $\sin(bx)$, but the limits of integration are different.

Looking at the [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform), it seems I should be getting something involving dirac delta functions. The limits of integration are really throwing me off though, since I can't use the $\delta(a-b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i(a-b)x}dx$ in this form.

Comment: If you let $f = \theta(x), \ g=\sin(bx)$ then your integral is equal to the fouriertransform of $f\cdot g$ which is equal to a convolution between $\hat{g}$ and $\hat{f}$>

Comment: Write $e^{-iax}=\cos ax-i\sin ax$.

Comment: @Olba12 What is $\theta(x)$?

Comment: The heaviside function.

Comment: This is a Laplace transform - Fourier transforms integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, this is a one-sided Laplace transform if you substitute  $ia = s$. http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplacePropTable.html http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-iax}\sin(bx)dx $$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\sigma + ia)x}\sin(bx)dx$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{ibx} - e^{-ibx} }{2i}e^{-(\sigma + ia)x}dx$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2i}e^{ibx}e^{-(\sigma + ia)x}dx -\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2i}e^{-ibx}e^{-(\sigma + ia)x}dx\right]$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \left[\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2i}e^{-(\sigma + ia -ib)x}dx -\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2i}e^{-(\sigma + ia+ib)x}dx\right]$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \dfrac{1}{2i} \left[-\dfrac{e^{-(\sigma + ia -ib)x}}{\sigma+ia-ib}\bigg\rvert_{0}^{\infty} +\dfrac{e^{-(\sigma + ia+ib)x}}{\sigma+ia+ib}\bigg\rvert_{0}^{\infty}\right]$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \dfrac{1}{2i}\left[\dfrac{1}{\sigma+ia-ib} - \dfrac{1}{\sigma+ia+ib}\right]$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \dfrac{1}{2i}\left[\dfrac{\sigma + ia +ib}{(\sigma+ia)^2+b^2} - \dfrac{\sigma +ia -ib}{(\sigma+ia)^2+b^2}\right]$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \dfrac{1}{2i}\left[\dfrac{2ib}{(\sigma+ia)^2+b^2}\right]$$
$$ = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} \dfrac{b}{(\sigma+ia)^2+b^2}$$
$$ = \dfrac{b}{b^2-a^2}$$

Strictly speaking, the region of convergence for the integration is for a real number $\sigma > 0$.  I don't have a rigorous justification for the limit as $\sigma \rightarrow 0$ to be valid; but the limit appears to be unambiguous and consistent with the result for $\sigma > 0$.

**Update to evaluate the integral as a Fourier Transform (vs. Laplace Transform)**

$$I(a, b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-iax}\sin(bx)dx$$
$$I(2\pi f, b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(bx) e^{-2\pi ifx}dx$$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(x) \sin(bx) e^{-2\pi ifx}dx$$
where $H(x)$ is the Heavyside unit step, which for this answer I'll choose as $H(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} \text{sgn}(x)$.

The integral is now in the form of a Fourier Transform of the product of $H(x)$ and $\sin(bx)$
$$ = \mathscr{F}\{H(x)\sin(bx)\} = \mathscr{F}\{H(x)\} * \mathscr{F}\{\sin(bx)\} = \mathscr{F}\left\{\dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} \text{sgn}(x)\right\} * \mathscr{F}\{\sin(bx)\}$$

Without going through the derivation of those individual Fourier transforms, as presented in *The Fourier Transform and Its Applications* by Ronald N. Bracewell,  I'll just substitute them in here without proof:

$$ = \left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(f)-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{i}{\pi f}\right] *\dfrac{i}{2}\dfrac{\pi}{|b|}\left[\delta\left(\dfrac{\pi}{b}f + \dfrac{1}{2}\right)-\delta\left(\dfrac{\pi}{b}f - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right]$$
$$ = \left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(f)-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{i}{\pi f}\right] *\dfrac{i}{2}\dfrac{\pi}{|b|}\left[\dfrac{\delta\left(f + \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)}{\left|\dfrac{\pi}{b}\right|}-\dfrac{\delta\left(f - \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)}{\left|\dfrac{\pi}{b}\right|}\right]$$
$$ = \left[\dfrac{1}{2}\delta(f)-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{i}{\pi f}\right] *\dfrac{i}{2}\left[\delta\left(f + \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)-\delta\left(f - \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)\right]$$
$$ = \dfrac{i}{4}\left[\delta\left(f + \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)-\delta\left(f - \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)\right] + \dfrac{1}{4\pi}\left[\dfrac{1}{f+\dfrac{b}{2\pi}}-\dfrac{1}{f-\dfrac{b}{2\pi}}\right]$$
$$ = \dfrac{i}{4}\left[\delta\left(f + \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)-\delta\left(f - \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)\right] + \left[\dfrac{b}{b^2-(2\pi f)^2}\right]$$
$$ = \dfrac{i}{4}\left[\delta\left(\dfrac{a}{2\pi} + \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)-\delta\left(\dfrac{a}{2\pi} - \dfrac{b}{2\pi}\right)\right] + \left[\dfrac{b}{b^2-a^2}\right]$$

Which is the correct answer on the imaginary axis in the s-plane (my earlier Laplace transform answer is the analytic continuation to the right hand side of the s-plane).

So the integral blows up at $b = \pm a$ still, just differently than in my first answer.

I'll note that the Dirac delta functions in this answer arise from the shift of $1/2$ (to convert $\text{sgn}(x)$ to $H(x)$) being multiplied with the $\sin(bx)$ term.  The other term is due to $\text{sgn}(x)$ being multiplied with the $\sin(bx)$ term.

Comment: @Andy_Walls I'm almost happy with your answer - this link (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790373/fourier-laplace-transform-of-heaviside-step-function-multiplied-to-sine) suggests that we have your answer plus two dirac deltas - could this be the difference that the limit $\sigma \to 0$ induces here?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(x)e^{-iax}\sin(bx) dx = \int_{0^{-}}^{\infty} H(x) e^{-iax}\sin(bx) dx$ is slightly different from the integral in the question.  I'm sure I can do the two-sided integration with the Heavyside unit step by introducing a factor of $e^{-\alpha x^2}$ and taking the limit as $\alpha$ goes to $0$, and probably get the Dirac delta functions to show up.  But that may only prove that a slightly different integral has a slightly different answer.

Comment: Just a comment about the convergence: the integral _does not_ converge in the usual sense for $\sigma = 0,$ it is easy to see if you split the real and imaginary parts of it, each of them can be transformed to something of form $\int_0^\infty \sin(\alpha x + \beta) dx.$

Comment: @Alexander_Rodin yes, my initial answer was nagging at me as being wrong. I updated the answer to add a solution using the Fourier transform vs. a Laplace transform.